# How to audit failure events for Windows security eventlog in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, event-viewer

i need to access `Audit Failure` under `Window log` -> `Security`  event instantly when it logs, is there any way to capture it instantly when it logs. i need to access real time attempts.
currently i am reading this from `EventLogEntry` class in c#, but i need a my application to run when `Audit Failure` occurs.

```
 foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
   {
     if (entry.EntryType==EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit)
       {
          ///
       }
   }
```

some thing similar to:

```
    EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog();
    myNewLog.Log = "MyCustomLog";                      

    myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
    myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

[Event log events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), some like this i want to trigger windows log also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get EventLogs using [EventLog.GetEventLogs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74e2ybbs.aspx) method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog log = EventLog.GetEventLogs().First(o => o.Log == "Security");
        log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        log.EntryWritten += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Entry.EntryType); };
        Console.WriteLine(log.LogDisplayName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: will this application display log details, when any log get written in Security section

Comment: as i discussed , i need real time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153322/missing-source-ip-address-and-source-port-number-in-event-log

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var eventLog = new EventLog();
    eventLog.Log = "Security";
    
    eventLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.TimeGenerated);
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the question is looking for. It asks for a way to get the "event instantly when it logs".