# missing network information in event log for windows 7 client (Event ID 4625)

Tags: c#, .net, networking, event-log, readeventlog

I have an application which will display event log  of `Security` -> `AuditFailure`in c#, i am reading it with `EventLogEntry` class's `Message` property, i am testing it on `Window server 2008 R2`

When a failure event log generated from machine like `Window Server 2008 R2` or `Windows XP` then it generates IP Address as well as Port Number under network information section, but log generated for `Windows 7` machine 
does not contain IP Address as well as Port Number.[image: Screen shot for log generated by window 7 machine]

Comment: there is nothing related to code, i am reading event log , if i read manually, then its the same

Comment: yes, actually this is written by system in event log and not able to find ip