# How can I check Audit logon events programatically?

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, group-policy

I would like to create a program that checks two values on my pc.

Would I have to check for these values in the registry or is there another place that I could check? If it is in the registry where could I find these values?

They are:
[image: Audit logon events]

Ideally I would like to write a c# program that would check these values for me.  However I'm not exactly sure where I can find them.

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate.  I am not asking to review the audit logs.  I am asking how to check audit event settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to audit failure events for Windows security eventlog in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15135717/608639).

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Asking how to check settings, not the log.